# Render the square wave form graph using PHP

Tags: php, charts, gd, fusioncharts

I would like to render the square wave form of graph using the only values of zero and one on certain time intervals.

I used fusion chart line graph to render the chart but when the values changes from zero to one the line goes very slanting but i would like to show it straight.

For example check out the attached image it shows the square wave form. Suggest me which open source script used to generate these kind of chart( may be using GD with PHP).
Anyother better idea ?

**EDITED THE LINK**

[Square Wave Form image](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/2127/squarewavegraph.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't see your image. Please fix.

Comment: It's a question of referer : if you copy the URL of the image and openit yourself (like, in another browser tab), you can see it instead of getting a 403

Comment: hey hobodave. Fixed the link. Check out the image.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [JpGraph](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/) to generate these kind of charts.

Answer (score 0):

PowerCharts, a sister product of FusionCharts now provides Step-line chart which can render line like this.

Check: http://www.fusioncharts.com/powercharts/charts/step-line/

Sample: http://www.fusioncharts.com/powercharts/gallery/StepLine1.html